# How to use redux reselect avoiding redundancy

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reselect

I have a redux state containing posts, which I store as a single object with the following shape:

```
posts: {
   1: { isPublic: true, content: 'foo' },
   2: { isPublic: true, content: 'bar' },
   3: { isPublic: false, content: 'foobar' },
}
```

I'm fetching the state using reselect from my component, and I have created 2 selectors for that:

```
const getPostsEntities = (state) => state.posts;


export const getPosts = createSelector(
    [ getPostsEntities ],
    (posts) => Object.keys(posts).map( id => posts[id])
);

export const getPublicPosts= createSelector(
    [ getPostsEntities ],
    (posts) => Object.keys(posts).map( id => posts[id]).filter( post => post.isPublic )

);
```

My doubt is about this part which seems redundant in any selector

> (posts) => Object.keys(posts).map( id => posts[id])

I thought about having the `getPostsEntities` return directly the array, but I'm having some issue understanding what's the best practice

Comment: `getPublicPosts` can re use getPosts and then you'll get posts as an array so you don't need to do `Object.keys(posts).map( id => posts[id])` again but just do `posts.filter`

Comment: What @HMR said, and you can use `(posts) => Object.values(posts)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @HMR, you can use one reselect selector inside another.  So `getPublicPosts` can be based on the memoized results from `getPosts`.  You can also use `Object.values()` instead of `Object.keys()`.

```
const getPostsEntities = (state: State) => state.posts;
 
export const getPosts = createSelector(
    [ getPostsEntities ],
    (posts) => Object.values(posts)
);

export const getPublicPosts = createSelector(
    [ getPosts ],
    (posts) => posts.filter(post => post.isPublic)
);
```